# Calling ASMX Web Service From C++ MFC Project

Tags: c++, mfc, asmx

I have a web service that have functions to retrieve data from database. (http://exampledomain.com/webservice/webservice.asmx) It's easy to add a web service in C# (Project->Add Service Reference->Advanced->Add Web Reference) but i don't have any knowledge about C++. Also there is no option in Project tab for adding reference. How can i add web service to C++ project and access it's functions and retrieve data?

Comment: C# has a lot of stuff built in. C++ does not (different design theology) so you need to write it yourself or use a library like gSoap or Axis/C

Answer (score 0):

Standard C++ or MFC do no provide a way to consume web services. However, it is possible to do so with [C++ REST SDK](https://casablanca.codeplex.com/). It's a cross-platform library that allows you to consume services, use json, asynchronous streams and other things.